# Calculating LCOM3?

Tags: java, metrics, code-metrics

Are there any opensource/free libraries that I can use to calculate the LCOM3 or LCOM4 Class Cohesion metric?  I want to write a tool that reads in java files and calculate this metric.

Comment: Different authors use different names for the various metrics.  Which authors are connected with "your" LCOM3 and LCOM4?

Comment: I am looking to calculate LCOM to determine cohesion over time.  You can read about the kind of metric I am looking for here: http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/codemetrics/index-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This metric is is available [in Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming metrics2 release has the Henderson-Sellers version of LCOM ("LCOM3").  You can get a pre-release version of the Eclipse plugin at http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/downloads/list.  The [StateOfFlow metrics](http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/16/eclipsemetrics) plugin also has it.